# Multiple suggestion chips selection in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Is there any way to select multiple options for single intent?

example-

bot: please select your hobbies? (suggestions chips options are = "Cricket", "Football", "Basketball", "Chess", "Reading" etc.)
user: want to select cricket, football and, chess

Is it possible to make multiple selections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, with clicking on chips you can only select one chips suggestion. However, you can handle this via a user utterance in followup intent.

bot: please select your hobbies? (suggestions chips options are = "Cricket", "Football", "Basketball", "Chess", "Reading" etc.)

user: My hobbies are **cricket and football**.

These you can extract in follow up intent.